# NADP and NADPH in in vitro metabolisme test

Tags: human-biology

I did an in vitro metabolism test using chicken liver S9 as the source of the enzyme. I did two different of method experiment. one was using NADP and second was using NADPH as the co-factor. my compound was fipronil, and I expect it to be metabolised become Fipronil sulfone (through oxidation reaction). The results, when I use NADP, fipronil sulfone formed was very low concentration, but in contrast, when using NADPH, I got high amount of fipronil sulfone. 
what is the different using NADP and NADPH in this experiment?
Thank you for sharing the informatio.
Kind regards

Alex

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by an "in vitro metabolism test"? What is chicken liver S9? What enzyme are you assaying? What is your assay? Fipronil is hardly a compound that the average user of this site will have heard of — I had to Google for it. If you want us to help you, you should write down the equation of this reaction, showing what you expect to happen. At the moment you seem to be telling us that you are assaying an oxidation reaction but you only get results with a reducing cofactor. You are obviously doing something wrong. We need more information to help you.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure your question is accurate?

NADP in solution does not exist... it can either be NADPH which is the reduced form (has gained an electron in the form of a H atom and now has the potential to give that electron to another molecule in the solution) or NADP+ which is the oxidised form (has lost an electron in the form of H atom and now has the potential to gain an electron from the solution).

In your experiment, Fiprinol to Fiprinol Sulfone is an oxidation reaction, so the enzyme catalyses the removal of an electron from Fipronol, and it does that with the help of NADP+, which is missing an electron itself and therefore takes it from Fiprinol (oxidises it) to give a high Fiprinol Sulfone yield.

Comment: This is really a comment rather than an answer. You are explaining what the reaction is but not why his assay isn't working, which was his (unanswerable) question.